# How do I get X-Forwarded-For in Apache with mod_proxy enables

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse, x-forwarded-for

I have configured reverse proxy with mod_proxy.

ProxyPreserveHost is On
ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are set.

However I need remote address of client in X-Forwarded-For header but it is not visible.

Tried almost all thread! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Solution was to disable "removeip" module in apache which was activated because of german privacy law.

It is at least worth a check :)